# How do I combine two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a initial dataframe `D`. I extract two data frames from it like this:

```
A = D[D.label == k]
B = D[D.label != k]
```

I want to combine `A` and `B` into one DataFrame. The order of the data is not important. However, when we sample `A` and `B` from `D`, they retain their indexes from `D`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: From `pandas v1.4.1`: The `frame.append` method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use `pandas.concat` instead.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

> **DEPRECATED:** `DataFrame.append` and `Series.append` were [deprecated in v1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append).

---

Use `append`:

```
df_merged = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

And to keep their indexes, set `ignore_index=False`.

Comment: This works. It creates a new DataFrame though. Is there a way to do it inline? That would be nice for when I'm loading huge amounts of data from a database in batches so I could iteratively update the DataFrame without creating a copy each time.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46661368/5717580

Comment: From `pandas v1.4.1`: The `frame.append` method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use `pandas.concat` instead.

Answer (score 223):

Use `pd.concat` to join multiple dataframes:

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Comment: I want to use this, but I'm trying to concatenate two columns of the same name o_O

Answer (score 100):

Merge across rows:

```
df_row_merged = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True)
```

Merge across columns:

```
df_col_merged = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 38):

If you're working with big data and need to concatenate multiple datasets calling `concat` many times can get performance-intensive.

If you don't want to create a new df each time, you can instead aggregate the changes and call `concat` only once:

```py
frames = [df_A, df_B]  # Or perform operations on the DFs
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

This is pointed out in the pandas docs under [concatenating objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) at the bottom of the section):

> **Note**: It is worth noting however, that `concat` (and therefore `append`)
> makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this
> function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use
> the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to update/replace the values of first dataframe `df1` with the values of second dataframe `df2`. you can do it by following steps —

**Step 1:** Set index of the first dataframe (df1)

```
df1.set_index('id')
```

**Step 2:** Set index of the second dataframe (df2)

```
df2.set_index('id')
```

and finally update the dataframe using the following snippet —

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Answer (score 3):

To join 2 pandas dataframes by column, using their indices as the join key, you can do this:

```
both = a.join(b)
```

And if you want to join multiple DataFrames, Series, or a mixture of them, by their index, just put them in a list, e.g.,:

```
everything = a.join([b, c, d])
```

See the pandas docs for [`DataFrame.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Answer (score 3):

Both the dataframe should have same column name else instead of appending records by row wise, it will append as separate columns.

```
df = df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# collect excel content into list of dataframes
data = []
for excel_file in excel_files:
    data.append(pd.read_excel(excel_file, engine="openpyxl"))

# concatenate dataframes horizontally
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
# save combined data to excel
df.to_excel(excelAutoNamed, index=False)
```

You can try the above when you are appending horizontally! Hope this helps sum1

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to attach two Pandas Data Frames horizontally:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

You must specify around what axis you intend to merge two frames.