# how to read nested json file in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I learned how to load and read `json` file in pandas dataframe. However, I have multiple json files about news and each `json` file hold a rather complicated nested structure to represent news content and its metadata. I need to read them in pandas dataframe for next downstream analysis. So I figured out how to load and read json file in python. However, the solution that I learned for my json file doesn't work for me. Here is example json data snippet on the fly: [example json file](https://jmp.sh/v/HYlIODnYJHk3nqhqroeM) and here is what I tried:

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = 'FakeNewsNetData/BuzzFeed/FakeNewsContent/'  // multiple json files
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

with open('json_files[0]') as f:
    data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line) for line in f)
```

but I didn't get expected pandas dataframe. How can I read `json` file with nested structure into pandas dataframe nicely? Is there anyone take a look example json data snippet and provide a possible idea to make this work in pandas dataframe? Any thoughts? Thanks

**source of json data**:

I used json data from this github repository: [FakeNewsNet Dataset](https://github.com/KaiDMML/FakeNewsNet/tree/master/Data/BuzzFeed/RealNewsContent), so you can browse the how original data looks like and create neat pandas dataframe from it. Any idea to get this done easily? Thanks again

**update 2**:

I tried following solution but it didn't work for me:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('FakeNewsContent/BuzzFeed_Fake_1-Webpage.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588852/pandas-read-nested-json)

Comment: @MayurBhangale I tried this too but it didn't work, any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import json

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

path_to_json = 'FakeNewsNetData/BuzzFeed/FakeNewsContent/'
json_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, "*.json"))
df = pd.concat((json_normalize(json.load(open(p))) for p in json_paths), axis=0)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)  # Optionally reset index.
```

This will load all your json files into a single dataframe.
It will also flatten the nested json hierarchy by adding '.' between the keys.

You will probably need to perform further data cleaning, for e.g., by replacing the NaNs with appropriate values. This can be done with the the dataframe's `fillna`, or by applying a function to transform individual values.

### Edit

As I mentioned in the comment, the data is actually messy, so words such as "View All Post" can be one of the values for "authors". See the JSON "BuzzFeed_Fake_26-Webpage.json" for an example.

To remove these entries and possibly others,

```
# This will be a set of entries you wish to remove.
# Here we only consider "View All Posts".
invalid_entries = {"View All Posts"}

import functools
def fix(x, invalid):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [i for i in x if i not in invalid]
    else:
        # You can optionally choose to return [] here to fix the NaNs
        # and to standardize the types of the values in this column
        return x

fix_author = functools.partial(fix, invalid=invalid_entries)
df["authors"] = df.authors.apply(fix_author)
```

Comment: Fixed the mistake. The `glob` function needs a path.

Comment: Can you provide an example in which you think the mapping is wrong? Note that the different JSON files have different number of keys and nesting. Therefore, when they are flattened into the same dataframe, there are bound to be missing entries. Also, entries corresponding to nested dictionary belongs to columns where their keys are joined by a '.'.

Comment: for example if you explore columns like `df.authors`, there is some extra text falsely included, and false column like `meta_data.DC.date.issued`, `meta_data.apple-mobile-web-app-capable`, `meta_data.article.author` and so on, which are not correct according to original `json` files. Seems python confused about when we mapping data from json to pandas dataframe. Any workable solution to fix this?

Comment: Like I said in my answer and in my comment above, columns such as `meta_data.DC.date.issued` **etc** are **new** columns added from **flattening** the nested JSON structure. If you don't introduct these new columns, you cannot merge the JSON files into a single dataframe because they have different level of nesting. A column such as `meta_data.app-mobile-web-app-capable` means the original json dict has nesting `{"metadata": {"apple-mobile-web-app-capable": <value>} }`.

Comment: do you think we can fix wrong entry for `df.author` column? I don't get it why `View all port` key words were added? can we avoid this?

Comment: If you inspect the json file for, say, "BuzzFeed_Fake_26-Webpage.json", you will see that under "authors", the value is a list `[Campus Reform", "View All Posts"]`. That is, "View All Posts" was part of the data meant for "authors". That is, the inclusion of "View All Posts" is not a problem with my code, but with the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to orient your `dataframe`. Try the below code to update your **Update 2** Approach:

```
x = {"top_img": "http://eaglerising.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/terrorism-2.jpg", "text": "On Saturday, September 17 at 8:30 pm EST, an explosion rocked West 23 Street in Manhattan, in the neighborhood commonly referred to as Chelsea, injuring 29 people, smashing windows and initiating street closures. There were no fatalities. Officials maintain that a homemade bomb, which had been placed in a dumpster, created the explosion. The explosive device was removed by the police at 2:25 am and was sent to a lab in Quantico, Virginia for analysis. A second device, which has been described as a \u201cpressure cooker\u201d device similar to the device used for the Boston Marathon bombing in 2013, was found on West 27th Street between the Avenues of the Americas and Seventh Avenue. By Sunday morning, all 29 people had been released from the hospital. The Chelsea incident came on the heels of an incident Saturday morning in Seaside Heights, New Jersey where a bomb exploded in a trash can along a route where thousands of runners were present to run a 5K Marine Corps charity race. There were no casualties. By Sunday afternoon, law enforcement had learned that the NY and NJ explosives were traced to the same person.\n\nGiven that we are now living in a world where acts of terrorism are increasingly more prevalent, when a bomb goes off, our first thought usually goes to the possibility of terrorism. After all, in the last year alone, we have had several significant incidents with a massive number of casualties and injuries in Paris, San Bernardino California, Orlando Florida and Nice, to name a few. And of course, last week we remembered the 15th anniversary of the September 11, 2001 attacks where close to 3,000 people were killed at the hands of terrorists. However, we also live in a world where political correctness is the order of the day and the fear of being labeled a racist supersedes our natural instincts towards self-preservation which, of course, includes identifying the evil-doers. Isn\u2019t that how crimes are solved? Law enforcement tries to identify and locate the perpetrators of the crime or the \u201cbad guys.\u201d Unfortunately, our leadership \u2013 who ostensibly wants to protect us \u2013 finds their hands and their tongues tied. They are not allowed to be specific about their potential hypotheses for fear of offending anyone.\n\nNew York City Mayor Bill de Blasio \u2013 who famously ended \u201cstop-and-frisk\u201d profiling in his city \u2013 was extremely cautious when making his first remarks following the Chelsea neighborhood explosion. \u201cThere is no specific and credible threat to New York City from any terror organization,\u201d de Blasio said late Saturday at the news conference. \u201cWe believe at this point in this time this was an intentional act. I want to assure all New Yorkers that the NYPD and \u2026 agencies are at full alert\u201d, he said. Isn\u2019t \u201can intentional act\u201d terrorism? We may not know whether it is from an international terrorist group such as ISIS, or a homegrown terrorist organization or a deranged individual or group of individuals. It is still terrorism. It is not an accident. James O\u2019Neill, the New York City Police Commissioner had already ruled out the possibility that the explosion was caused by a natural gas leak at the time the Mayor made his comments. New York\u2019s Governor Andrew Cuomo was a little more direct than de Blasio saying that there was no evidence of international terrorism and that no specific groups had claimed responsibility. However, he did say that it is a question of how the word \u201cterrorism\u201d is defined. \u201cA bomb exploding in New York is obviously an act of terrorism.\u201d Cuomo hit the nail on the head, but why did need to clarify and caveat before making his \u201cobvious\u201d assessment?\n\nThe two candidates for president Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump also weighed in on the Chelsea explosion. Clinton was very generic in her response saying that \u201cwe need to do everything we can to support our first responders \u2013 also to pray for the victims\u201d and that \u201cwe need to let this investigation unfold.\u201d Trump was more direct. \u201cI must tell you that just before I got off the plane a bomb went off in New York and nobody knows what\u2019s going on,\u201d he said. \u201cBut boy we are living in a time\u2014we better get very tough folks. We better get very, very tough. It\u2019s a terrible thing that\u2019s going on in our world, in our country and we are going to get tough and smart and vigilant.\u201d\n\nUnfortunately, an incident like the Chelsea explosion reminds us how vulnerable our country is particularly in venues defined as \u201csoft targets.\u201d Now more than ever, America needs strong leadership which is laser-focused on protecting her citizens from terrorist attacks of all genres and is not afraid of being politically incorrect.\n\nThe views expressed in this opinion article are solely those of their author and are not necessarily either shared or endorsed by EagleRising.com", "authors": ["View All Posts", "Leonora Cravotta"], "keywords": [], "meta_data": {"description": "\u201cWe believe at this point in this time this was an intentional act,\" de Blasio said. Isn\u2019t \u201can intentional act\u201d terrorism?", "og": {"site_name": "Eagle Rising", "description": "\u201cWe believe at this point in this time this was an intentional act,\" de Blasio said. Isn\u2019t \u201can intentional act\u201d terrorism?", "title": "Another Terrorist Attack in NYC...Why Are we STILL Being Politically Correct", "locale": "en_US", "image": "http://eaglerising.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/terrorism-2.jpg", "updated_time": "2016-09-22T10:49:05+00:00", "url": "http://eaglerising.com/36942/another-terrorist-attack-in-nyc-why-are-we-still-being-politically-correct/", "type": "article"}, "robots": "noimageindex", "fb": {"app_id": 256195528075351, "pages": 135665053303678}, "article": {"section": "Political Correctness", "tag": "terrorism", "published_time": "2016-09-22T07:10:30+00:00", "modified_time": "2016-09-22T10:49:05+00:00"}, "viewport": "initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no", "googlebot": "noimageindex"}, "canonical_link": "http://eaglerising.com/36942/another-terrorist-attack-in-nyc-why-are-we-still-being-politically-correct/", "images": ["http://constitution.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/confederatemonument_poll_pop.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46772-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/eagle-rising-logo3-1.png", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46729-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46764-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46731-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-52ePUfP6_NxQ_.gif", "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9b4601287436c60e1c7c5b65d725151f?s=112&d=mm&r=g", "http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=2&c2=22315475&cv=2.0&cj=1", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46784-featured-300x130.png", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/terrorism-2-800x300.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/coup-375x195.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/crtv_300x600_1.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46774-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/superstar-375x195.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46763-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46612-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46761-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46642-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46735-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46750-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46755-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46752-featured-300x130.png", "http://eaglerising.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/terrorism-2.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46743-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46712-featured-300x130.jpg", "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/9b4601287436c60e1c7c5b65d725151f?s=100&d=mm&r=g", "http://2lv0hm3wvpix464wwy2zh7d1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/46757-featured-300x130.png"], "title": "Another Terrorist Attack in NYC\u2026Why Are we STILL Being Politically Correct \u2013 Eagle Rising", "url": "http://eaglerising.com/36942/another-terrorist-attack-in-nyc-why-are-we-still-being-politically-correct/", "summary": "", "movies": [], "publish_date": {"$date": 1474528230000}, "source": "http://eaglerising.com"}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index')
print df
```

Reading from JSON file:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('FakeNewsContent/BuzzFeed_Fake_1-Webpage.json', 'r') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
print df
```

Comment: I copied the json from one your json file into x

Comment: can we make this code more efficient like how can I merge bunch of json files with same structure into one pandas dataframe? Anyway to make your code smart and efficient? Any more thoughts? Thank you

Comment: @beyond_inifinity Updated my solution added new approach

Comment: @beyond_inifinity Merging two `df` calls for a different question. However you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850345/how-to-combine-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas for merging related solutions.