# how to combine csv data in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have two CSV files, and I want to combine them in one file. My first CSV file is called vector_train.csv and the second is label_train.csv

```
vector_train.csv
v1,v2,v3,v100
12,32,15,30
55,72,45,90

label_train.csv
sentence,label
bad voice,0
good voice,1
```

I want the output like this

```
vector_train.csv
v1,v2,v3,v100,label
12,32,15,30,0
55,72,45,90,1
```

please help me

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: So you want your code to always ignore the first thing before the comma for your second file?

Comment: yes because the sentence has been converted to be a vector

Comment: read the csv with pandas read csv, then do:  vector_train_df['label'] = label_train_df['label']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said how you join the 2 data frames. I assume you want to join them line by line:

```
vector = pd.read_csv('vector_train.csv')
label = pd.read_csv('label_train.csv')

vector['label'] = label['label']
vector.head()
```

Output:

```
v1  v2  v3  v100  label
12  32  15  30    0
55  72  45  90    1
```

Comment: wow big thanks its work, i was try use loop,makes me very confused

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe to read the csv files
`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html`

and then combine the two files as one dataframe 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850345/how-to-combine-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas`

and then save in a csv file 
`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can import both csv into 2 different dataframe and then you can add an extra column to the first dataframe and assign it equal to the column of second dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
vector_train_df = pd.read_csv("vector_train.csv")
label_train_df = pd.read_csv("label_train.csv")
vector_train_df['label'] = label_train_df['label']
```