# Create the most complete table from two tables with missing rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1:      df2:

   A         A

1 10      2 21
2 20      3 31
5 50      4 41
6 60      5 51
```

and want to merge both DataFrames to the most complete one based on their indexes. The result should be the following:

```
df_full

   A

1 10
2 20
3 31
4 41
5 50
6 60
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850345/how-do-i-combine-two-data-frames) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for this:

```
df1.combine_first(df2).astype(int)

    col1
1    10
2    20
3    31
4    41
5    50
6    60
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!