# Concatenating two different Data frames in Pandas Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add the below 2 data frames like below,writing the result to external file and by default the separator as comma(,) but I need the separator as space, any idea how to achieve this?

```
df16 = pd.DataFrame("    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="'""'" DATATYPE ="'"'""+df2+""'"'">")
df18 = pd.DataFrame("NAME ="'"'""+df17+""'"'" />")

result = pd.concat ([df16]+[df18], axis=1)

result.to_csv('C:\\SAM\\TEST.dat',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,header=0,index=False,mode='a+')
```

**Actual Output:**

```
<SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="CHAR"/>,NAME ="BA_RECCODE"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATATYPE ="CHAR"/> NAME ="BA_RECCODE"
```

Comment: Is all this strings doesnt make syntax error?

Comment: Welcome.
[df16]+[df18] may be the cause of trouble. Try [df16, df18].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine two data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850345/how-do-i-combine-two-data-frames)

Comment: I tried [df16, df18] but still I can't ignore comma(,)