# want to change the value of variable using list in loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tradingview-api

```
symbols = ["NIFTY", "ITC", "BBC", ....etc]
```

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval

tv = TvDatafeed()

tv = TvDatafeed(username, password, chromedriver_path=None)

tv = TvDatafeed(auto_login=true)

nifty_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='NIFTY',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1)

print(nifty_index_data)
#result will be like this in pandas>>>>>>>
```

| datetime | symbol | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-20 08:45:00 | NSE:NIFTY | 19943.15 | 19991.85 | 19935.45 | 19987.05 | 60215122.0 |

There is around 1060 stocks/symbols and we have to run script again-again to scrap different  data for different symbols like this >>>

```
# nifty
nifty_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='NIFTY',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1)

# ITC
ITC_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='ITC',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1)


# RELIANCE
RELIANCE_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='RELIANC',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1)

print(nifty_data)
print(ITC_data)
print(RELIANCE_data)

#this will return 3 different tables

#i need data in 1 datafame
```

I need all symbol data in one data frame like this>>>

| datetime | symbol | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-20 03:45:00 | NSE:BORORENEW | 474.50 | 485.00 | 473.45 | 483.75 | 89517.0 |
| 2023-07-20 03:45:00 | NSE:NIFTY | 19841.15 | 19844.00 | 19784.55 | 19813.35 | 19934954.0 |

**AND I ALSO DONT WAN'T TO RUN SCRIPT AGAIN-AGAIN BY CHANGING SYMBOL NAME**

**PLESE HELP THIS IS MY FIRST INTERVIEW PRESENTATION**

**LIBARRY THAT I USED>>>[TVDATAFEED](https://github.com/baselsm/tvdatafeed) **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine two dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850345/how-do-i-combine-two-dataframes)

Comment: I dont see support for more than one symbol in that api, but the git repo seems easy enough to follow if you wanted to fork it.

Comment: @JonSG Congrats for 10k rep:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

symbols = ["NIFTY", "ITC", "RELIANC"]

result = pd.concat([tv.get_hist(symbol=symbol,exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1) for symbol in symbols])
```